# NSNull isEqualToString: unrecognized selector on ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

Well my code was like this:

I have two strings, `place and date.` I am using them like this:

```
cell.datePlace.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",date,place];
```

In some entries, the output is like this:

```
"21/10/2012, <null>"
"21/11/2012, None"
"21/12/2013, London"
```

My app does not crash but I want the place to be visible only when is not null and not equal to None.

So I tried this:

```
 NSString * place=[photo objectForKey:@"place"];


if ([place isEqualToString:@"None"]) {
                cell.datePlace.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date];
            } else {
                cell.datePlace.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",date,place];
            }
```

Problem was when place was `<null>` my app crashed and I got this error:

```
[NSNull isEqualToString:] unrecognized selector send to instance
```

So, i tried this:

```
if (place) {
            if ([place isEqualToString:@"None"]) {
                cell.datePlace.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date];
            } else {
                cell.datePlace.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",date,place];
            }
        } else {
            cell.datePlace.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date];
        }
```

But the problem remains.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I guess your source data is coming from JSON or similar (something where data is being parsed in and missing data is being set to `NSNull`). It's the `NSNull` that you need to deal with and aren't currently.

Basically:

```
if (place == nil || [place isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    // handle the place not being available 
} else {
    // handle the place being available
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's coming from JSON. it'w working now. I will accept the answer!

Comment: Note that `NSNull` is a singleton object, so you can just compare with `place == [NSNull null]`.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
if (! [place isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]) {
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
if (place) {
   ...
}
```

Note: NSNull object is not nil, so the `if (place)` will be true then.

Comment: The `place != nil` check is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Use [NSNull null]:

```
if ([place isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
    // What happen if place is null

}
```